# Edit filter options of a UIList

Tags: python, scripting

I would like to be able to set custom filter values for a UIList with code.
To do so, I would like to get a reference to an instance of a UIList such that I can set its properties (such as `filter_name`).

I use the `UILayout` method `template_list` ([documentation](https://docs.blender.org/api/2.79/bpy.types.UILayout.html#bpy.types.UILayout.template_list)). This is the only way of which I know to draw a UIList - but it has no return value, and I have no access to the UIList instance created somewhere in the background.

Is there any way to access UIList instances?

Comment: There is an advanced example for filtering using `draw_filter()`, `filter_items()` and bitwise operators in [the docs](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.UIList.html#advanced-uilist-example-filtering-and-reordering) in case you haven't seen that already.

Comment: I know the example. it only allows me to access the filter properties from inside of the UIList class - that doesn't work for me, as the filter I need to set depends on from which panel the list is drawn.